# QGIS Server installation (Debian) : error message

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-server, request, debian

I want to install QGIS Server on Debian.

I added the official QGIS repository which allowed to install the version of QGIS Server 3.30. For information, the QGIS project that I am trying to serve is version 3.28 and not 3.30.
This is the current error message I am getting now:

```
curl http://SERVEUR_NAME/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
[1] 395943
[2] 395944
root@SERVEUR_NAME:/home/qgis/projects# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.3.0">
  <ServiceException code="OperationNotSupported">Please add or check the value of the REQUEST parameter</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
^C
[1]- Done curl http://SERVEUR_NAME/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS
[2]+ Finished VERSION=1.3.0
```

---

When I enter `http://SERVER/qgisserver?MAP=/home/qgis/projects/world.qgs&LAYERS=continents&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=200&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180`

I obtain :

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at SERVER Port 80
```

For information, when I type this URL into the navigator: `http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`

I obtain:

```
  This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms"
    xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/wms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/sld_capabilities.xsd http://www.qgis.org/wms http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetSchemaExtension">
    <Service>
        <Name>WMS</Name>
        <Title>QGIS Server Demo</Title>
        <Abstract>
            <![CDATA[ This is a simple World map that showcases QGIS Server capabilities. ]]>
        </Abstract>
        <KeywordList>
            <Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
            <Keyword>QGIS Server World</Keyword>
        </KeywordList>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple"
            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi"/>
        <ContactInformation>
            <ContactPersonPrimary>
                <ContactPerson>Tudor Bărăscu</ContactPerson>
                <ContactOrganization>qgis.org</ContactOrganization>
            </ContactPersonPrimary>
            <ContactElectronicMailAddress>tudor.barascu@qtibia.ro</ContactElectronicMailAddress>
        </ContactInformation>
        <Fees>conditions unknown</Fees>
        <AccessConstraints>None</AccessConstraints>
    </Service>
    <Capability>
        <Request>
            <GetCapabilities>
                <Format>text/xml</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </GetCapabilities>
            <GetMap>
                <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
                <Format>image/png; mode=16bit</Format>
                <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
                <Format>image/png; mode=1bit</Format>
                <Format>application/dxf</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </GetMap>
            <GetFeatureInfo>
                <Format>text/plain</Format>
                <Format>text/html</Format>
                <Format>text/xml</Format>
                <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
                <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
                <Format>application/json</Format>
                <Format>application/geo+json</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </GetFeatureInfo>
            <sld:GetLegendGraphic>
                <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
                <Format>application/json</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </sld:GetLegendGraphic>
            <sld:DescribeLayer>
                <Format>text/xml</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </sld:DescribeLayer>
            <qgs:GetStyles>
                <Format>text/xml</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?"/>
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </qgs:GetStyles>
        </Request>
        <Exception>
            <Format>XML</Format>
        </Exception>
        <sld:UserDefinedSymbolization UserLayer="0" UserStyle="1" InlineFeature="0" RemoteWFS="0"
            SupportSLD="1" RemoteWCS="0"/>
        <Layer queryable="1">
            <Title>QGIS Server Demo</Title>
            <Abstract>
                <![CDATA[ This is a simple World map that showcases QGIS Server capabilities. ]]>
            </Abstract>
            <KeywordList>
                <Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
                <Keyword>QGIS Server World</Keyword>
            </KeywordList>
            <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
            <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
            <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
            <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
            <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <westBoundLongitude>-189</westBoundLongitude>
                <eastBoundLongitude>189</eastBoundLongitude>
                <southBoundLatitude>-123</southBoundLatitude>
                <northBoundLatitude>118</northBoundLatitude>
            </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
            <BoundingBox minx="-19970716.649" maxx="19970716.649" CRS="EPSG:3857"
                miny="-44927335.428" maxy="44927335.428"/>
            <BoundingBox minx="-123" maxx="118" CRS="EPSG:4326" miny="-189" maxy="189"/>
            <BoundingBox minx="-19960441.004" maxx="19960441.004" CRS="EPSG:900913"
                miny="-19293806.199" maxy="30772816.154"/>
            <Layer queryable="1">
                <Name>airports</Name>
                <Title>airports</Title>
                <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
                <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                    <westBoundLongitude>-175.135635</westBoundLongitude>
                    <eastBoundLongitude>179.195443</eastBoundLongitude>
                    <southBoundLatitude>-53.781475</southBoundLatitude>
                    <northBoundLatitude>78.246717</northBoundLatitude>
                </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <BoundingBox minx="-19496009.708" maxx="19947945.359" CRS="EPSG:3857"
                    miny="-7128878.351" maxy="14502137.594"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-53.781475" maxx="78.246717" CRS="EPSG:4326" miny="-175.135635"
                    maxy="179.195443"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-19496009.708" maxx="19947945.359" CRS="EPSG:900913"
                    miny="-7128878.351" maxy="14502137.594"/>
                <Style>
                    <Name>default</Name>
                    <Title>default</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=airports&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=default&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
                <MinScaleDenominator>1</MinScaleDenominator>
                <MaxScaleDenominator>3.66192e+06</MaxScaleDenominator>
            </Layer>
            <Layer queryable="1">
                <Name>places</Name>
                <Title>places</Title>
                <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
                <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                    <westBoundLongitude>-175.220565</westBoundLongitude>
                    <eastBoundLongitude>179.216648</eastBoundLongitude>
                    <southBoundLatitude>-41.299974</southBoundLatitude>
                    <northBoundLatitude>64.150024</northBoundLatitude>
                </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <BoundingBox minx="-19505464.015" maxx="19950305.897" CRS="EPSG:3857"
                    miny="-5056688.948" maxy="9387963.682"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-41.299974" maxx="64.150024" CRS="EPSG:4326" miny="-175.220565"
                    maxy="179.216648"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-19505464.015" maxx="19950305.897" CRS="EPSG:900913"
                    miny="-5056688.948" maxy="9387963.682"/>
                <Style>
                    <Name>default</Name>
                    <Title>default</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=places&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=default&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
            </Layer>
            <Layer queryable="1">
                <Name>countries</Name>
                <Title>countries</Title>
                <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
                <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                    <westBoundLongitude>-180</westBoundLongitude>
                    <eastBoundLongitude>180</eastBoundLongitude>
                    <southBoundLatitude>-90</southBoundLatitude>
                    <northBoundLatitude>83.623597</northBoundLatitude>
                </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <BoundingBox minx="-20037508.343" maxx="20037508.343" CRS="EPSG:3857"
                    miny="-44927335.428" maxy="18418382.138"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-90" maxx="83.623597" CRS="EPSG:4326" miny="-180" maxy="180"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-20037508.343" maxx="20037508.343" CRS="EPSG:900913"
                    miny="-17054781.687" maxy="18418382.138"/>
                <Style>
                    <Name>classified_by_name</Name>
                    <Title>classified_by_name</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=countries&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=classified_by_name&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
                <Style>
                    <Name>classified_by_population</Name>
                    <Title>classified_by_population</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=countries&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=classified_by_population&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
            </Layer>
            <Layer queryable="1">
                <Name>countries_shapeburst</Name>
                <Title>countries_shapeburst</Title>
                <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
                <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
                <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                    <westBoundLongitude>-180</westBoundLongitude>
                    <eastBoundLongitude>180</eastBoundLongitude>
                    <southBoundLatitude>-90</southBoundLatitude>
                    <northBoundLatitude>83.623597</northBoundLatitude>
                </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <BoundingBox minx="-20037508.343" maxx="20037508.343" CRS="EPSG:3857"
                    miny="-44927335.428" maxy="18418382.138"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-90" maxx="83.623597" CRS="EPSG:4326" miny="-180" maxy="180"/>
                <BoundingBox minx="-20037508.343" maxx="20037508.343" CRS="EPSG:900913"
                    miny="-17054781.687" maxy="18418382.138"/>
                <Style>
                    <Name>blue</Name>
                    <Title>blue</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=countries_shapeburst&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=blue&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
                <Style>
                    <Name>default</Name>
                    <Title>default</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=countries_shapeburst&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=default&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
                <Style>
                    <Name>green</Name>
                    <Title>green</Title>
                    <LegendURL>
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:type="simple"
                            xlink:href="http://SERVER/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=countries_shapeburst&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=green&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0"
                        />
                    </LegendURL>
                </Style>
                <MinScaleDenominator>1</MinScaleDenominator>
                <MaxScaleDenominator>2.5e+08</MaxScaleDenominator>
            </Layer>
        </Layer>
    </Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

Comment: You should read your QGIS server logs. If needed, increase your DEBUG level. Are you sure you have a MAP defined by default on your server ? Otherwise, you need to provide it.

Comment: Could the error message mean that the request is truncated for some reason after the "&" signs?

Comment: @etrimaille  I have no log file generated in /var/log/qgis/ . I post below updates and more test results. This time with a MAP defined. I used the project and données provided with the documentation.

Comment: `http://SERVER/qgisserver?MAP=/home/qgis/projects/world.qgs&LAYERS=continents&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=200&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180` is not a complete GetMap request it's missing  two mandatory parameters `STYLES` and `FORMAT`

Comment: For curl you need to have your parametrised url in quotes to get the response you desire like `curl "http://SERVEUR_NAME/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem fix thanks to this post :
https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2023-March/052763.html

There was a big typo in the official doc...
How to point out this big error in the doc which personally hurt me a lot? ;-)

Comment: You have a button at the top : "Edit on GitHub", or you can create a ticket on the GitHub repository linked.